# Making Leaflet layer control with Mapbox default "Off"

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

We've implemented a layer control just like the Mapbox example below on our app. It works great, but we'd like to have some of the layers default as toggled "off". Any help?

Here's our code:

```
    function displayLayerMaps(init_lat, init_lon, addr, parcel_data) {

    //$("#layer-map").html("");
    //$("#layer_map_ui").html("");
    var $layers = $('#layer_map_ui').empty();       

    if (layer_map) {
        layer_map.remove();
    }

    layer_map = L.mapbox.map('layer-map', "dirturban.k6hmjki6").setView([init_lat, init_lon], 22);
    layer_map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

    //addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('dirturban.7d1a3087'), 'Parcels', 7, $layers, layer_map);
    addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('dirturban.84de85b4'), 'Satellite View', 1, $layers, layer_map);
    addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('dirturban.460b53c7'), 'Detailed Zoning', 2, $layers, layer_map);
    addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('dirturban.7adcb589'), 'Incentive Zoning', 3, $layers, layer_map);
    addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('dirturban.c05e9c5a'), 'Urban Village', 4, $layers, layer_map);
    addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('dirturban.b92c50a4'), 'Pavement Edge', 5, $layers, layer_map);
    addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('dirturban.6fa753d7'), 'Park Boundaries', 6, $layers, layer_map);
    addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('dirturban.e2744409'), 'City Defined Trees', 7, $layers, layer_map);
    // and parcels

    addMarker(layer_map,init_lat,init_lon, addr, "small", "#cc0000");
```

And rendered, it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwR2e.jpg

Thank you,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Just create an instance of `L.mapbox.map` and use `null` as the `mapid` parameter:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGF1bC12ZXJob2V2ZW4iLCJhIjoiZ1BtMWhPSSJ9.wQGnLyl1DiuIQuS0U_PtiQ';

var map = L.mapbox.map('mapbox', null, {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0
});
```

Then create instances of the maps you need and add them to your control with out calling the `.addTo` method on them:

```
var layers = {
    Streets: L.mapbox.tileLayer('examples.map-i87786ca'),
    Outdoors: L.mapbox.tileLayer('examples.ik7djhcc'),
    Satellite: L.mapbox.tileLayer('examples.map-igb471ik')
}

L.control.layers(layers).addTo(map);
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vGplMcA7bYBFeCXigUsj?p=preview

Code taken largely from: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/toggle-baslayers/

Comment: Why would i need that? I gave you a complete working example with explanation on how it works. Is there something not clear?